# angular error [$rootScope:inprog] when calling two things in one event

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.createAccount = "Create Account";
$scope.isDisabled = false;

$scope.createUser = function(account){
     user.createAccount(account);
     $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';
     $scope.isDisabled = true;
};
```

> [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest at angular.js:38

If I do comment

```
$scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';
$scope.isDisabled = true;
```

it works without error what is the issue please suggest

In service i use this function

```
function rootScoopApply($scope, fn)
    {
         var phase = $scope.$root.$$phase;
         if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
             if (fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
                 fn();
             }
         } else {
             $scope.$apply(fn);
         }  
    }
```

and call it

```
user.rootScoopApply($rootScope, function() {        
    $scope.createUser = function(account){

         user.createAccount(account);
         $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';
         $scope.isDisabled = true;

    }

  });
```

Comment: are you using $apply somewhere in your code in angular context ?

Comment: are you using `$scope.$apply` anywhere

Comment: $('#supersized').hide(); this is only thing im using in this page

Comment: Yes $scope.$apply are in other files too why this creates problem ?

Comment: angular.js  will monitor all changes by default. `$scope.$apply()` should occur as close to the async event binding as possible. check here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: I create the service for this 

var phase = $scope.$root.$$phase;
         if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
             if (fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
                 fn();
             }
         } else {
             $scope.$apply(fn);
         }

Comment: user.rootScoopApply($rootScope, function() {  
 $scope.createUser = function(account){
   
   user.createAccount(account);
         $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';
         $scope.isDisabled = true;
    
    }
     
  });

Comment: could you post the code in question? It is difficult to read.

Comment: Updated please take a look. How to overcome this issue pls guide

Comment: Any Idea @Sibi Raj

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides wrappers for common native JS async behaviors:

- Events => ng-click
- Timeouts => $timeout
- jQuery.ajax() => $http

This is just a traditional async function with a `$scope.$apply()` called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just occurred.

`$scope.$apply()` should occur as close to the async event binding as possible.

Do NOT randomly sprinkle it throughout your code. If you are doing
`if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` it's because you are not high enough in the call stack.

Whenever possible, use AngularJS services instead of native. If you're creating an AngularJS service (such as for sockets) it should have a `$scope.$apply()` anywhere it fires a callback or broadcast/emit.

For example, `$rootScope.$apply($rootScope.$broadcast('receivedMsg', msg)); is valid`

[source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())